# Swagger UI customization in DRF (Django) using drf-spectacular

Tags: django, swagger, openapi, drf-spectacular

I am currently trying to document apis of my DRF project.
I have read many articles on how to customize swagger api definition .

I have found out that i can use extend_schema() and serializers to customize api definitions.

But the problem is i have to 100s of APIs in my project.
and using extend_schema() i will have to edit 100s of files.

Is there a way to define all APIs in a single file ?

like for this example : https://editor.swagger.io/
there is a yml file, where we can edit all API definitions.

is there something similar that i can do for my DRF project ?